# Typescript React TS2307 cannot find module json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm currently running into a strange error. I'm trying to load a json file using import with the json-loader.

```
import * as ApiConfig from "../../src/conf.json";
```

I have created a typings.d.ts to define both css and json modules.

```
declare module "*.json" {
   const value: any;
   export default value;
}


declare module "*.css" {
    const content: any;
    export default content;
}
```

When I don't have my typings.d.ts file opened in my WebStorm I have this error

```
Error:(1, 28) TS2307:Cannot find module '../../src/conf.json'.
```

But when I have it opened I don't have this error.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here are my loaders in my webpack.config.js

```
loaders: [
            {
                exclude: [
                    /\.html$/,
                    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    /\.css$/,
                    /\.json$/,
                    /\.svg$/
                ],
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, '../') ],
                exclude: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles') ],
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
                    cacheDirectory:true
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, '../') ],
                exclude: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles') ],
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: "svg-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader"
            }
        ]
```

Thanks

Comment: `Error:(1, 28) TS2307:Cannot find module '../../src/conf.json'.` it means that the path is wrong

Comment: I've double checked my path and it's the right one. Even stranger like I said, the app is loading the JSON. It's just in webstorm that I have this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually a bug in WebStorm, it has been fixed in version 2017.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Use **var** instead of **import**.

```
var json = require('../../src/conf.json');
```